# Реализция сетевой части

Tags: android

Привет. Задали реализовать серверную часть игры. Заключается в том чтобы передавать инфу между двумя телефонами (android). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: При помощи беспроводных технологий. Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Что вы уже пытались сделать, и что не получилось?

Comment: Мне нужно направление в котором надо работать. Я думаю попробоватать через сокеты. Должно получиться?

Answer (score 1):

Пишите серверную часть и через неё передаете данные между устройствами.
Используете Bluetooth, Wi-Fi для организации канала передачи данных между устройствами.